# How to use IsMatch regular Expression for no matching characters?

Tags: c#

I try to check if a string contains any characters, but '\' and '^' are not allowed.

```
Regex nameValidator = new Regex("^[\\^]+$");
```

This doesn't work:

```
!nameValidator.IsMatch(myString)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ^ inside of character class has a different meaning than outside. It means negation of class characters. So my regex will allow everything besides `\` and `^`

```
Regex nameValidator = new Regex(@"^[^^\\]+$");
```

Comment: new Regex(@"^[^^\\]+$"); will have two negations. The caret must be escaped with a backslash, not by another caret.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster did you try that?

Comment: I just did and learned something. Sorry for premature criticism. Have an upvote :-)

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster kein problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
Regex nameValidator = new Regex(@"^[^\^\\]+$");

string sample_text = "hello world";
bool isMatch = nameValidator.IsMatch(sample_text); // true

sample_text = @"Hello ^  \world ";
isMatch = nameValidator.IsMatch(sample_text); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ escapes the backslash for the string literal in C#. Your regex (as the regex engione sees it) is therefore

```
^[\^]+$
```

Which is valid, but not what you wanted. (The cared gets escaped by the backslash)
Change to:

```
new Regex("[\\\\\\^]+");
```

or use the @ before the string literal (recommended)

```
new Regex(@"[\\\^]+");
```

You have to escape both the backslash and the caret, so triple backslash. To use them in a string literal without the @, you have to escape every backslash again, so you have six of them.

Comment: These are not working. I want my string to contain 0-9, a-z and any other character but NOT \ or ^

Comment: Right. Like your original regex, it had ^ and $ to match only the whole string. Corrected. Note that it matches any string with ^or \ in it. I find it more elegant to do the negation in the regex, rather than using !isMatch()